# How to auto-restart a docker-compose cluster when EC2 instance reboots

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I had this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  kibana:
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - es01
      - es02
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.3.1
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01:9200
  es01:
    restart: always
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.1
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
  es02:
    restart: always
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.1
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local
```

but these containers did not restart when the ec2 instance rebooted. Maybe I should use something like this instead:

```
docker-compose up -d --restart   # the --restart flag maybe?
```

?

Notice the "restart" properties in the yml file, guess they didn't do anything in this case?

**But there is no --restart flag:**

> ```
> (account-api) ubuntu@account_management5-interos:~/interos/repos/elastic-search-app$
> ```
>
> docker-compose up -d --restart
>       Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.
>
> ```
> Unless they are already running, this command also starts any linked services.
>
> The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container. When
> the command exits, all containers are stopped. Running `docker-compose up -d`
> starts the containers in the background and leaves them running.
>
> If there are existing containers for a service, and the service's configuration
> or image was changed after the container's creation, `docker-compose up` picks
> up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted
> volumes). To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the `--no-recreate`
> flag.
>
> If you want to force Compose to stop and recreate all containers, use the
> `--force-recreate` flag.
>
> Usage: up [options] [--scale SERVICE=NUM...] [SERVICE...]
>
> Options:
>     -d, --detach               Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
>                                print new container names. Incompatible with
>                                --abort-on-container-exit.
>     --no-color                 Produce monochrome output.
>     --quiet-pull               Pull without printing progress information
>     --no-deps                  Don't start linked services.
>     --force-recreate           Recreate containers even if their configuration
>                                and image haven't changed.
>     --always-recreate-deps     Recreate dependent containers.
>                                Incompatible with --no-recreate.
>     --no-recreate              If containers already exist, don't recreate
>                                them. Incompatible with --force-recreate and -V.
>     --no-build                 Don't build an image, even if it's missing.
>     --no-start                 Don't start the services after creating them.
>     --build                    Build images before starting containers.
>     --abort-on-container-exit  Stops all containers if any container was
>                                stopped. Incompatible with -d.
>     -t, --timeout TIMEOUT      Use this timeout in seconds for container
>                                shutdown when attached or when containers are
>                                already running. (default: 10)
>     -V, --renew-anon-volumes   Recreate anonymous volumes instead of retrieving
>                                data from the previous containers.
>     --remove-orphans           Remove containers for services not defined
>                                in the Compose file.
>     --exit-code-from SERVICE   Return the exit code of the selected service
>                                container. Implies --abort-on-container-exit.
>     --scale SERVICE=NUM        Scale SERVICE to NUM instances. Overrides the
>                                `scale` setting in the Compose file if present.
> ```

I am looking for the equivalent to:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 \
    --restart unless-stopped \    # RESTART
    --name 'interos-mongo' \
    'mongo:4.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact `docker-compose` doesn't handle real restarts, these are done by `dockerd`.

The restart policy written in the compose configuration file will eventually be written to the container's restart policy, which you can check with the following command.

```
docker inspect --format '{{.HostConfig.RestartPolicy}}' you-container-ID-or-name
```

Going back to your question, have you set up dockerd to auto starting? i.e. `systemctl enable docker`

xref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/